# Python script to type something in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to make a python script that opens a separate terminal window and immediately enters a command without the user having to type anything.

I use `os.system("gnome-terminal")` to open the second terminal but I have no clue how to make it go ahead an enter a command. I tried `os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'python ./example.py'")` but it doesn't even open a second terminal, but while I have `os.system("gnome-terminal")` it opens one fine.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here : [how-can-i-spawn-new-shells-to-run-python-scripts-from-a-base-python-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469655/how-can-i-spawn-new-shells-to-run-python-scripts-from-a-base-python-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try a few ways

such as:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo apt-get update; exec bash\"'")
```

Although on windows i opt for a sub-process, heres an example from stack:

```
import subprocess as sub

sub.Popen('cmd /K dir')
sub.Popen(['cmd', '/K', 'dir'])
```

And replace dir with whichever command you wish to use. The /k is used to keep the commandline open and run the command.

here is some other links that answer the question fairly well most of the answers actually being valid, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163422/using-python-to-open-a-shell-environment-run-a-command-and-exit-environment)

Comment: Awesome glad it worked! could you consider marking the question as solved if it worked?