# Open shell environment and run a series of command using Python

Tags: python

Seems duplicate of [Using Python to open a shell environment, run a command and exit environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163422). I want to run the ulimit command in the shell environment in Redhat. Procedure: Open shell environment, run ulimit commands on shell, get the result and exit the shell environmnet. Referencing the above solution, I tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def read_limit():
    p = Popen('sh', stdin=PIPE)
    file_size = p.communicate('ulimit -n')
    open_files = p.communicate('ulimit -f')
    file_locks = p.communicate('ulimit -x')
    return file_size, open_files, file_locks
```

But I got error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) says:

> send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

After that, the pipe will be closed.

You can use

```
p.stdin.write("something")
p.stdin.flush()
result = p.stdout.readline()
```

for your three commands and then

```
p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

at the end to terminate it