# How to start a shell from a python script

Tags: python

I'd like to run a script which does some setup then opens up a shell with that environment. So rather than then doing

```
$ python
>>> # do some setup
>>> # start doing what I really came here to do
```

I want to do

```
$ python my_script.py
>>> # start doing what I really came here to do
```

Comment: You could write the file, then type `from filename import *` into the shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163422/using-python-to-open-a-shell-environment-run-a-command-and-exit-environment

Comment: @gmdev perhaps, but the answers I have so far are concise and relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your script with the `-i` argument:

```
python -i my_script.py
```

This will execute `my_script.py` and drop to an interactive shell afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

you can do some thing like this

```py
import code

variables = {"test": True}
shell = code.InteractiveConsole(variables)
shell.interact()
```

now it will open python shell and you can access test variable directly