# Equivalent of Python's subprocess.communicate in Rust?

Tags: io, rust, child-process

I'm trying to port this Python script that sends and receives input to a helper process to Rust:

```py
import subprocess
data = chr(0x3f) * 1024 * 4096
child = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, _ = child.communicate(data)
assert output == data
```

My attempt worked fine until the input buffer exceeded 64k because presumably the OS's pipe buffer filled up before the input was written.

```
use std::io::Write;

const DATA: [u8; 1024 * 4096] = [0x3f; 1024 * 4096];

fn main() {
    let mut child = std::process::Command::new("cat")
                        .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped())
                        .stdin(std::process::Stdio::piped())
                        .spawn()
                        .unwrap();
    match child.stdin {
        Some(ref mut stdin) => {
            match stdin.write_all(&DATA[..]) {
                Ok(_size) => {}
                Err(err) => panic!(err),
            }
        }
        None => unreachable!(),
    }
    let res = child.wait_with_output();
    assert_eq!(res.unwrap().stdout.len(), DATA.len())
}
```

Is there a `subprocess.communicate` equivalent in Rust? Maybe a `select` equivalent? Can mio be used to solve this problem? Also, there seems to be no way to close stdin.

The goal here is to make a high performance system, so I want to avoid spawning a thread per task.

Comment: - "*so I want to avoid spawning a thread per task*" - `Popen.communicate` does in fact use threads when working with more than two pipes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12965273/257568. So, in your case, can the communication be limited to two pipes?

Comment: @ArtemGr Do you mean **less** than two pipes? The comment in the linked question says "If we are only using one pipe, or no pipe at all".

Comment: @Shepmaster Right, sorry, if there's less than one pipe then threading or non-blocking I/O is unnecessary.

Comment: @ArtemGr lol, *less than one* would only be zero pipes, and *any* I/O would be unnecessary ;-)

Comment: Popen.communicate does not use threads on OSX or linux: instead it uses poll (see   def _communicate_with_poll(self, input) in https://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Lib/subprocess.py )

Comment: - "*instead it uses poll*" - So... Async IO is not yet integrated into the Rust standard library (https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1081) so your best bet for something like `poll` is an external crate, like `mio`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it wasn't a small amount of code to get this done, and I needed a combination of mio and nix, because mio wouldn't set AsRawFd items to be nonblocking when they were pipes, so this had to be done first.

Here's the result

```
extern crate mio;
extern crate bytes;

use mio::*;
use std::io;
use mio::unix::{PipeReader, PipeWriter};
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd;
use nix::fcntl::FcntlArg::F_SETFL;
use nix::fcntl::{fcntl, O_NONBLOCK};
extern crate nix;

struct SubprocessClient {
    stdin: PipeWriter,
    stdout: PipeReader,
    output : Vec<u8>,
    input : Vec<u8>,
    input_offset : usize,
    buf : [u8; 65536],
}


// Sends a message and expects to receive the same exact message, one at a time
impl SubprocessClient {
    fn new(stdin: PipeWriter, stdout : PipeReader, data : &[u8]) -> SubprocessClient {
        SubprocessClient {
            stdin: stdin,
            stdout: stdout,
            output : Vec::<u8>::new(),
            buf : [0; 65536],
            input : data.to_vec(),
            input_offset : 0,
        }
    }

    fn readable(&mut self, _event_loop: &mut EventLoop<SubprocessClient>) -> io::Result<()> {
        println!("client socket readable");


        match self.stdout.try_read(&mut self.buf[..]) {
            Ok(None) => {
                println!("CLIENT : spurious read wakeup");
            }
            Ok(Some(r)) => {
                println!("CLIENT : We read {} bytes!", r);
                self.output.extend(&self.buf[0..r]);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                return Err(e);
            }
        };
        return Ok(());
    }

    fn writable(&mut self, event_loop: &mut EventLoop<SubprocessClient>) -> io::Result<()> {
        println!("client socket writable");

        match self.stdin.try_write(&(&self.input)[self.input_offset..]) {
            Ok(None) => {
                println!("client flushing buf; WOULDBLOCK");
            }
            Ok(Some(r)) => {
                println!("CLIENT : we wrote {} bytes!", r);
                self.input_offset += r;
            }
            Err(e) => println!("not implemented; client err={:?}", e)
        }
        if self.input_offset == self.input.len() {
            event_loop.shutdown();
        }
        return Ok(());
    }

}

impl Handler for SubprocessClient {
    type Timeout = usize;
    type Message = ();

    fn ready(&mut self, event_loop: &mut EventLoop<SubprocessClient>, token: Token,
             events: EventSet) {
        println!("ready {:?} {:?}", token, events);
        if events.is_readable() {
            let _x = self.readable(event_loop);
        }
        if events.is_writable() {
            let _y = self.writable(event_loop);
        }
    }
}



pub fn from_nix_error(err: ::nix::Error) -> io::Error {
    io::Error::from_raw_os_error(err.errno() as i32)
}

fn set_nonblock(s: &AsRawFd) -> io::Result<()> {
    fcntl(s.as_raw_fd(), F_SETFL(O_NONBLOCK)).map_err(from_nix_error)
                                             .map(|_| ())
}


const TEST_DATA : [u8; 1024 * 4096] = [40; 1024 * 4096];
pub fn echo_server() {
    let mut event_loop = EventLoop::<SubprocessClient>::new().unwrap();
    let process =
           Command::new("cat")
           .stdin(Stdio::piped())
           .stdout(Stdio::piped())
           .spawn().unwrap();
    let raw_stdin_fd;
    match process.stdin {
      None => unreachable!(),
      Some(ref item) => {
          let err = set_nonblock(item);
          match err {
             Ok(()) => {},
             Err(e) => panic!(e),
          }
          raw_stdin_fd = item.as_raw_fd();
      },
    }
    let raw_stdout_fd;
    match process.stdout {
      None => unreachable!(),
      Some(ref item) => {
          let err = set_nonblock(item);
          match err {
             Ok(()) => {},
             Err(e) => panic!(e),
          }
          raw_stdout_fd = item.as_raw_fd();},
    }
    //println!("listen for connections {:?} {:?}", , process.stdout.unwrap().as_raw_fd());
    let mut subprocess = SubprocessClient::new(PipeWriter::from(Io::from_raw_fd(raw_stdin_fd)),
                                               PipeReader::from(Io::from_raw_fd(raw_stdout_fd)),
                                               &TEST_DATA[..]);
    let stdout_token : Token = Token(0);
    let stdin_token : Token = Token(1);
    event_loop.register(&subprocess.stdout, stdout_token, EventSet::readable(),
                        PollOpt::level()).unwrap();

    // Connect to the server
    event_loop.register(&subprocess.stdin, stdin_token, EventSet::writable(),
                        PollOpt::level()).unwrap();

    // Start the event loop
    event_loop.run(&mut subprocess).unwrap();
    let res = process.wait_with_output();
    match res {
       Err(e) => {panic!(e);},
       Ok(output) => {
          subprocess.output.extend(&output.stdout);
          println!("Final output was {:}\n", output.stdout.len());
       },
    }
    println!("{:?}\n", subprocess.output.len());
}

fn main() {
  echo_server();
}
```

Basically the only way to close stdin was to call process.wait_with_output since the Stdin has no close primitive

Once this happened, the remaining input could extend the output data vector.

There's now a crate that does this

https://crates.io/crates/subprocess-communicate

Comment: I just released a crate to solve this issue https://crates.io/crates/subprocess-communicate

Answer (score -1):

In *this* particular example, you know that the input and output amounts are equivalent, so you don't need threads at all. You can just write a bit and then read a bit:

```
use std::io::{self, Cursor, Read, Write};

static DATA: [u8; 1024 * 4096] = [0x3f; 1024 * 4096];
const TRANSFER_LIMIT: u64 = 32 * 1024;

fn main() {
    let mut child = std::process::Command::new("cat")
        .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .stdin(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Could not start child");

    let mut input = Cursor::new(&DATA[..]);
    let mut output = Cursor::new(Vec::new());

    match (child.stdin.as_mut(), child.stdout.as_mut()) {
        (Some(stdin), Some(stdout)) => {
            while input.position() < input.get_ref().len() as u64 {
                io::copy(&mut input.by_ref().take(TRANSFER_LIMIT), stdin).expect("Could not copy input");
                io::copy(&mut stdout.take(TRANSFER_LIMIT), &mut output).expect("Could not copy output");
            }
        },
        _ => panic!("child process input and output were not opened"),
    }

    child.wait().expect("Could not join child");
    let res = output.into_inner();

    assert_eq!(res.len(), DATA.len());
    assert_eq!(&*res, &DATA[..]);
}
```

If you didn't have that specific restriction, you will need to use `select` from the libc crate, which requires file descriptors for the pipes so will probably restrict your code to running on Linux / OS X.

You could also start threads, one for each pipe (and reuse the parent thread for one of the pipes), but you've already ruled that out.

Comment: Interesting...this other stackoverflow question hints at possible use of mio to solve the problem, but no further explanation is given http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611742/how-do-i-read-the-output-of-a-child-process-without-blocking-in-rust

Comment: We can also assume this is another type of process like gunzip where the input and output ratios are unpredictable